# How to change login order when there are two or more IDs in Ubuntu

Tags: login-screen

I was using one account. But, there was a problem with this account. New accounts are not a problem at all.

- I do it when I log in.
- I have to choose the second ID with the arrow keys.
- I want to set the second ID as default (up, first).

What should I do?

Comment: What in the world does this even mean?

Answer (score 0):

Accounts on login screen are sorted by the frequency of logins. So your second ID will switch its position once you log in into it more time than into the first ID.

You can also backup your first ID home folder, then create new account, replace its home dir with your backup and change its owner.

Comment: Even so,
There must be a way to fix it.
That's the program.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature

Comment: Somewhere the number of logins is recorded
The editor will fix it.